# Reverting to an old npm package version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm currently developing npm packages and I'm publishing alpha versions for testing code (e.g. 1.0.16-alpha.1). It appears that the old versions get erased in the npm repository which is causing big problems.

First of all, is this normal behaviour? If it is normal, secondly, is there any way I can keep them in npm? Thanks.

EDIT: I did some testing - when I run on the command line `npm install <pkg>@old-version`, it works. When I run `npm install` in a package where it is a `devDependancy`, it sometimes errors. I haven't found an obvious pattern yet but do they get deleted? I guess that's all I need to know.

Comment: *"It appears that the old versions get erased in the npm repository"* What makes you think that?

Comment: @FelixKling Just been a couple of errors when I've ran `npm install` - checked the logs and it said version cannot be found.

Comment: *"I haven't found an obvious pattern yet..."* Most likely the version range you specified in your `package.json` files doesn't include the published version. Try https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/ .

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, I'll certainly take a look at this. Apprecaited